# How do I push a SQLite database from Mac to non-rooted Device?

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I push an SQLite database from my Mac back to my app overwriting the old database?

I want the simplest and latest answer:

- There is no SD card on the Pixel - so no SD card solutions.
- The device is not rooted and will not be. No root solutions.
- If possible an explorer / command line way to do this first,
- as a last resort a programmatic way to pull it

Any ideas?

Comment: On a non-rooted device you will not have permission to overwriting the old database. You could push the file over to somewhere that you have permission using adb (the mac version). Then programmatically open the file and copy the data into the old database.

Comment: What location would you recommend? and any idea on an abd command line example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question. This solution works for non-rooted devices (even without sdcard)! No code required in your app. Both from the terminal :

**Pull a SQLite database from your App to your Mac**

First be in the directory you want the db to turn up in then:

```
adb -d shell "run-as your.package.name cat databases/source_database_name" > target_database_name
```

**Push your new/modified SQLite database from Mac back to your App**

```
adb push database_name /sdcard/database_name
adb shell
run-as your.package.name
cat /sdcard/database_name > databases/database_name
```

This solution seems much more sustainabable and repeatable for developers like myself who want to rapidly create/edit the SQLite databases on a Mac and send them back and forth with ease.